# SQL or PHP mistake? Distance calculation

Tags: php, mysql, html, math

I have a problem with my file. I'm making Travian Clone script and we went really far. Now we decided to add artefacts into game.

Goal is to show closest artefacts to the current village we are in. The code is:

```
function getDistance($coorx1, $coory1, $coorx2, $coory2) {
          $max = 2 * WORLD_MAX + 1;
          $x1 = intval($coorx1);
          $y1 = intval($coory1);
          $x2 = intval($coorx2);
          $y2 = intval($coory2);
          $distanceX = min(abs($x2 - $x1), $max - abs($x2 - $x1));
          $distanceY = min(abs($y2 - $y1), $max - abs($y2 - $y1));
          $dist = sqrt(pow($distanceX, 2) + pow($distanceY, 2));

          return round($dist, 1);
      }


        unset($reqlvl);
        unset($effect);
        $arts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."artefacts WHERE id > 0");
        $rows = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($arts)) {
            $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `' . TB_PREFIX . 'wdata` WHERE `id` = ' . $row['vref']);
            $coor2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            $wref = $village->wid;
            $coor = $database->getCoor($wref);
            $dist = getDistance($coor['x'], $coor['y'], $coor2['x'], $coor2['y']);

            $rows[$dist] = $row;

        }
        ksort($rows, SORT_ASC);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="icon"><img class="artefact_icon_'.$row['type'].'" src="img/x.gif" alt="" title=""></td>';
            echo '<td class="nam">';
            echo '<a href="build.php?id='.$id.'">'.$row['name'].'</a> <span class="bon">'.$row['effect'].'</span>';
            echo '<div class="info">';
            if($row['size'] == 1){
                   $reqlvl = 10;
                   $effect = "village";
               }elseif($row['size'] == 2 OR $row['size'] == 3){
                   $reqlvl = 20;
                   $effect = "account";
               }
            echo '<div class="info">Treasury <b>'.$reqlvl.'</b>, Effect <b>'.$effect.'</b>';
            echo '</div></td><td class="pla"><a href="karte.php?d='.$row['vref'].'&c='.$generator->getMapCheck($row['vref']).'">'.$database->getUserField($row['owner'],"username",0).'</a></td>';
            echo '<td class="dist">'.getDistance($coor['x'], $coor['y'], $coor2['x'], $coor2['y']).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
?>
```

but the code seems to be wrong because its showing all same distances. 14.8 to me. I know i maybe have bad explanation but u will probably understand what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help with your current code I'm afraid but you could try using the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) instead:

```
// Where: 
// $l1 ==> latitude1 
// $o1 ==> longitude1 
// $l2 ==> latitude2 
// $o2 ==> longitude2 
function haversine ($l1, $o1, $l2, $o2) { 
  $l1 = deg2rad ($l1); 
  $sinl1 = sin ($l1); 
  $l2 = deg2rad ($l2); 
  $o1 = deg2rad ($o1); 
  $o2 = deg2rad ($o2); 

  $distance = (7926 - 26 * $sinl1) * asin (min (1, 0.707106781186548 * sqrt ((1 - (sin ($l2) * $sinl1) - cos ($l1) * cos ($l2) * cos ($o2 - $o1))))); 

  return round($distance, 2);
}
```

Credit goes to [this post](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=339) on go4expert.com, I've used this function in the past and found it works very well.

Comment: yes, everything is fine except distance number. It's well sorted but number is like 988.82690262283

Comment: What should it be like? If you need it to two decimal places I've updated the answer above to do that :)

Comment: actually my village is on coordinates 0|-8 , village that is first on list is on 1|-8 so distance should be 1 and not 988 :S